# Sprite Kit + A* pathfinding = choppy and freezes

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, freeze, path-finding

I'm trying to learn xcode by making a game with sprite kit and have gotten relatively far. I've done some programming before and I learn quickly but after several hours of debugging my game I've almost given up.

I have built a map of lots of blocks (32x32px) and 1-4 characters that uses A* pathfinding to find a path.

- [Here is a video of the characters moving choppy](http://sv.tinypic.com/r/2rdiyis/8)

It works but I have two problems:

1. The path is calculated correctly and the char moves but when the char animates to the next block there is a little paus and he moves to the next block. This little paus makes the animation seem choppy, like the char is walking -> micropaus -> walking.
   The path is stored in an nsmutablearray and the method calls itself after completed SKAction (completion) to animate the next move. Between the completion and animation of the new move, there is this micropaus of the character.
2. When the char calculates a path the game freezes for a little time. When I have 4 chars the game freezes each time a new path is being calculated. Why is that?

When I click the block that the char should move to I invoke:

```
-(void)moveToward:(tileMap*)selBlock {
    BOOL pathFound = NO;

    if (currentStepAction) {
        self.pendingMove = selBlock;
        return;
    }

    self.StepListOpen = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.StepListClosed = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.shortestPath = nil;

    tileMap *fromTile = self.parentBlock;
    tileMap *toTile = selBlock;

    [self addToOpenSteps:[[ShortestPathStep alloc] initWithBlock:fromTile]];

    do {

        ShortestPathStep *currentStep = [self.StepListOpen objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.StepListClosed addObject:currentStep.theBlock];
        [self.StepListOpen removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        if (CGPointEqualToPoint(currentStep.theBlock.position, toTile.position)) {
            pathFound = YES;
            [self constructPathAndMove:currentStep];
            self.StepListOpen = nil;
            self.StepListClosed = nil;
            break;
        }

        NSArray *adjSteps = [_scene nearbyBlocks:currentStep.theBlock];

        for (tileMap *v in adjSteps) {
            ShortestPathStep *step = [[ShortestPathStep alloc] initWithBlock:v];
            if ([self.StepListClosed containsObject:step.theBlock]) {
                continue;
            }

            int moveCost = [self costToMove:currentStep toAdjacentStep:step];
            NSUInteger index = [self.StepListOpen indexOfObject:step.theBlock];

            if (index == NSNotFound) {
                step.parent = currentStep;
                step.gScore = currentStep.gScore + moveCost;
                CGPoint fromBlock = CGPointMake([[step.theBlock.name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,1)] floatValue], [[step.theBlock.name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8,1)] floatValue]);
                CGPoint toBlock = CGPointMake([[toTile.name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,1)] floatValue], [[toTile.name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8,1)] floatValue]);
                step.hScore = [self computeHscore:fromBlock toCoord:toBlock];
                [self addToOpenSteps:step];
            } else {
                step = [self.StepListOpen objectAtIndex:index];
                if ((currentStep.gScore + moveCost) < step.gScore) {
                    step.gScore = currentStep.gScore + moveCost;
                    [self.StepListOpen removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                    [self addToOpenSteps:step];
                }
            }
        }
    } while ([self.StepListOpen count] > 0);

    if (!pathFound) {
       NSLog(@"No path found.");
    }
}
```

If it finds a path it calls

```
- (void)constructPathAndMove:(ShortestPathStep *)step {
    self.shortestPath = [NSMutableArray array];
    do {
        if (step.parent != nil) {
            [self.shortestPath insertObject:step atIndex:0];
        }
        step = step.parent;
    } while (step != nil);

    [self popStepAndAnimate];
}
```

Now we move to popStepAndAnimate, the method that is called over and over again until the char has arrived to the destination.

```
-(void)popStepAndAnimate {

    self.currentStepAction = nil;

    if (self.pendingMove != nil) {
        tileMap *moveTarget = pendingMove;
        self.pendingMove = nil;
        self.shortestPath = nil;
        [self moveToward:moveTarget];
        return;
    }

    if (self.shortestPath == nil) {
        return;
    }


    // WE HAVE REACHED OUR BLOCK! CHECK IF ITS CLICKED OR STROLLING
    if ([self.shortestPath count] == 0) {
        self.shortestPath = nil;
        return;
    }

    ShortestPathStep *s = [self.shortestPath objectAtIndex:0];

    CGPoint futurePosition = s.theBlock.position;
    CGPoint currentPosition = self.parentBlock.position;
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(futurePosition, currentPosition);

    if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y)) {
        if (diff.x > 0) { [self runAnimation:_faceRight speed:0.1]; } else { [self runAnimation:_faceLeft speed:0.1]; }
    } else {
        if (diff.y > 0) { [self runAnimation:_faceUp speed:0.2]; } else { [self runAnimation:_faceDown speed:0.2]; }
    }

    self.parentBlock = s.theBlock;

    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:s.theBlock.position duration:0.7];
    SKAction *callbackAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{ [self popStepAndAnimate]; }];
    self.currentStepAction = [SKAction sequence:@[moveAction, callbackAction]];
    [self.shortestPath removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [self runAction:currentStepAction];
}
```

Comment: As you mention in your question, you should provide related code then community can see what is wrong. Whenever you have time please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of help centre.

Comment: It would probably be worth posting the bit of code which invokes the path finding algorithm

Comment: I added a little code where it's going wrong :) Thankful for every bit of help I can get. Been trying for days to get it smoother and without the freeze experience :D